# Instruments gives me 'SessionInactive', when trying to measure MemoryAllocations or MemoryLeaks on an MT app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

when trying to analyze an MonoTouch app using Apple "Instruments", it
gives me almost always after 4 seconds:

"Device Connection Failed"
"Failed to start Instruments daemon for 'iOS' on 'XYZ' (v4.3.3)' (SessionInactive)
"Please reconnect the device"

What am i doing wrong?
Is it, that my app takes too long to start up.
Or do i need an special build type to allow Instruments to connect?

One time i was able to have "MemoryAllocation" running stable for more than 4 seconds.

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. It happens when I try to run the Leaks instrument, which requires the Allocations instrument, I guess. I can run the Leaks instrument without the Allocations instrument without any problems, but then I can't get the the information that Allocations provides like from what method the leak originates.

I haven't been able to find much about it.

EDIT: I don't know if this is what fixed it, but I killed the app instance that was running on my iPad and then ran instruments again. I did not get the failure with "SessionInactive" and it seems to be running fine now.

I also found a similar topic on the [Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/452244). It didn't really help me, but it might help you.

EDIT 2: It's not perfect. It only runs for a few minutes, but it's better than not at all.